# After pushing and modify, files become not staged

Tags: git

I am using git and working on eclipse project after some modification I have done the following :

```
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "message"
$ git git push origin master
$ git status
```

and I get that all file are staged.
but when I modify  a file and check status I get that this file become not staged, whereas I expect that the files displayed in green :)

Comment: Once you commit, there should be no files "staged". When you change a file, it won't magically become staged, just modified. You need to do an `add` to stage the modifications (like you do before the commit shown).

Comment: You mean that i shoud add all modified files after each commit ?

Comment: The way git works is that it only commits *staged* changes. So when you modify files, you then tell git which of those changes you want to commit by using the `add` command before you use the `commit` command (you don't need to commit all changes!). In other words, you add the modified files you want to commit *before* the commit.

Comment: It's clear now thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Before files "are displayed in green", which means that they are staged, you have to add them to the staging area:

```
$ git add -a
$ git status
```

This should now show your changed files in the staging area (or "in green").

Comment: Yes I have added them by $ git add  --all.